# How do I give each user a private address for transactions

Tags: blockchain, addresses

I have a web app in React Typescript with supabase as a database. I want to integrate the blockchain with it in order to track work done between users.

How would I give each user an private address for my smart contract? Ideally this address would be created at sign up along with the user account.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look in HD wallets.

We call then custodial wallet. Where the user does not own the key but you provide access to it.

You most likely want to derive multiple address from a path. Once you understand these you can create multiple wallet with one key or create multiple key derived from one path.

Answer (score 0):

**Ofcourse Yes!** Here's a breakdown of how you'd integrate a blockchain to track work progress between users, focusing on assigning private addresses to each user within your React TypeScript app with Supabase.

**Conceptual Overview**

**Wallet Choice:** Decide whether your users will manage their own pre-existing non-custodial wallets (e.g., MetaMask) or if you'll handle wallet creation on their behalf.

**User Sign-Up:** Connect blockchain address generation/association with your Supabase sign-up process.

**Smart Contract Interactions:** Your smart contract(s) will track work, likely referencing user addresses to log contributions.
Web App Display: The React frontend fetches Supabase user data and any linked, on-chain work history from your smart contract.

**Key Considerations**

**Blockchain & Smart Contract:** Select the blockchain (Ethereum, Solana, etc.) that fits your needs and deploy the smart contract(s) to track work assignments/completions.

**Web3 Library:** You'll need a library like Ethers.js or Web3.js to interact with the blockchain in your React frontend.
Security:

Handling private keys, especially with custody, requires EXTREME caution. Educate yourself on best practices.

Auditing smart contracts is vital if handling significant value.
Methods for Address Assignment

**1.  User Connects Existing Wallet**

**Simpler Integration:** User signs in with a wallet like MetaMask. You simply read their address.

**User Responsibility:** They need pre-existing blockchain knowledge and management of their keys.

**2.  App-Generated Wallets**

**Seamless Onboarding:** Your app generates addresses at sign-up.

**Security Challenge:** Handling private keys on behalf of users is HIGHLY risk-sensitive.

**You must consider:**
Secure, encrypted storage on the backend (potentially alongside Supabase).
Clear user education about key recovery processes.

**Technical Outline (App-Generated Approach)**

**Blockchain Library:** Install chosen library for your target blockchain.

**Supabase + Sign-Up:** In your sign-up flow, upon successful Supabase account creation:
Generate new key pair using your blockchain library.
Safely store the **public address** in Supabase, linked to the user's record.
Crucially: Properly store the **private key**, considering encryption and
potential user-controlled recovery or export mechanisms.

**Smart Contract Calls:** When interacting with your contract:
Retrieve the user's private key (with immense caution, ideally on backend),
Sign transactions from your React app via Web3 library using that key.

**Backend(NodeJs) Example:**

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

// ... Your Supabase setup ...

// User sign-up route handler
async function handleSignUp(username, password) {
    // 1. Create Supabase user (your existing logic)  
    const { user, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({ email, password }); 

    // 2. Generate Ethereum wallet
    const wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
    const address = wallet.address; 
    const privateKey = wallet.privateKey; // CAUTION: HANDLE WITH EXTREME CARE

    // 3. Securely store in Supabase (ideally with strong encryption)
    await supabase
        .from('users') 
        .update({ ethereum_address: address, ethereum_private_key: privateKey }) 
        .eq('id', user.id); 
}
```

**Caveats**

This is a simplified overview. Robust implementation demands attention to security and error handling.
The app-generated address approach incurs greater development complexity and security risk over leveraging existing wallets.